# Need help walking data structures (_KPCR, _KPRCB, _KTHREAD, etc) based on PsGetCurrentProcess disassembled code

Tags: assembly, struct, 64-bit, offset

I've been studying the three-line assembly code taken from Windbg on a Windows 8.1 (64 bit) computer. I've been told that the below assembly code returns a pointer to a EPROCESS object. I however understand the very first line which walks the _KPCR struct object until it reaches offset +0x180 Prcb member of this struct. Then it walks the _KPRCB struct and eventually  points to offset +0x008 of this same struct which is represented by CurrentThread _KTHREAD object member.

Could someone now explain the second line and how this function points to a EPROCESS structure ?

```
lkd> uf nt!PsGetCurrentProcess
nt!PsGetCurrentProcess:
fffff801`2f640490 65488b042588010000 mov     rax,qword ptr gs:[188h]    ;this points to _KTHREAD (CurrentThread)
fffff801`2f640499 488b80b8000000     mov     rax,qword ptr [rax+0B8h]
fffff801`2f6404a0 c3                 ret
```

I've added the respective structures that should help:

```
lkd> dt _KPCR
nt!_KPCR
   +0x000 NtTib            : _NT_TIB
   +0x000 GdtBase          : Ptr64 _KGDTENTRY64
   +0x008 TssBase          : Ptr64 _KTSS64
   +0x010 UserRsp          : Uint8B
   +0x018 Self             : Ptr64 _KPCR
   +0x020 CurrentPrcb      : Ptr64 _KPRCB
   +0x028 LockArray        : Ptr64 _KSPIN_LOCK_QUEUE
   +0x030 Used_Self        : Ptr64 Void
   +0x038 IdtBase          : Ptr64 _KIDTENTRY64
   +0x040 Unused           : [2] Uint8B
   +0x050 Irql             : UChar
   +0x051 SecondLevelCacheAssociativity : UChar
   +0x052 ObsoleteNumber   : UChar
   +0x053 Fill0            : UChar
   +0x054 Unused0          : [3] Uint4B
   +0x060 MajorVersion     : Uint2B
   +0x062 MinorVersion     : Uint2B
   +0x064 StallScaleFactor : Uint4B
   +0x068 Unused1          : [3] Ptr64 Void
   +0x080 KernelReserved   : [15] Uint4B
   +0x0bc SecondLevelCacheSize : Uint4B
   +0x0c0 HalReserved      : [16] Uint4B
   +0x100 Unused2          : Uint4B
   +0x108 KdVersionBlock   : Ptr64 Void
   +0x110 Unused3          : Ptr64 Void
   +0x118 PcrAlign1        : [24] Uint4B
   +0x180 Prcb             : _KPRCB

    lkd> dt _KPRCB
    nt!_KPRCB
   +0x000 MxCsr            : Uint4B
   +0x004 LegacyNumber     : UChar
   +0x005 ReservedMustBeZero : UChar
   +0x006 InterruptRequest : UChar
   +0x007 IdleHalt         : UChar
   +0x008 CurrentThread    : Ptr64 _KTHREAD
   +0x010 NextThread       : Ptr64 _KTHREAD
   +0x018 IdleThread       : Ptr64 _KTHREAD
   +0x020 NestingLevel     : UChar
   +0x021 ClockOwner       : UChar
   +0x022 PendingTickFlags : UChar
   +0x022 PendingTick      : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x022 PendingBackupTick : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x023 PrcbPad00        : [1] UChar
   +0x024 Number           : Uint4B
   +0x028 RspBase          : Uint8B
   +0x030 PrcbLock         : Uint8B
   +0x038 PriorityState    : Ptr64 Char
   +0x040 ProcessorState   : _KPROCESSOR_STATE
   +0x5f0 CpuType          : Char
   +0x5f1 CpuID            : Char
   +0x5f2 CpuStep          : Uint2B
   +0x5f2 CpuStepping      : UChar
   +0x5f3 CpuModel         : UChar
   +0x5f4 MHz              : Uint4B
   +0x5f8 HalReserved      : [8] Uint8B
   +0x638 MinorVersion     : Uint2B
   +0x63a MajorVersion     : Uint2B
   +0x63c BuildType        : UChar
   +0x63d CpuVendor        : UChar
   +0x63e CoresPerPhysicalProcessor : UChar
   +0x63f LogicalProcessorsPerCore : UChar
   +0x640 ParentNode       : Ptr64 _KNODE
   +0x648 GroupSetMember   : Uint8B
   +0x650 Group            : UChar
   +0x651 GroupIndex       : UChar
   +0x652 PrcbPad05        : [2] UChar
   +0x654 ApicMask         : Uint4B
   +0x658 CFlushSize       : Uint4B
   +0x660 AcpiReserved     : Ptr64 Void
   +0x668 InitialApicId    : Uint4B
   +0x670 LockQueue        : [17] _KSPIN_LOCK_QUEUE
   +0x780 PPLookasideList  : [16] _PP_LOOKASIDE_LIST
   +0x880 PPNxPagedLookasideList : [32] _GENERAL_LOOKASIDE_POOL
   +0x1480 PPNPagedLookasideList : [32] _GENERAL_LOOKASIDE_POOL
   +0x2080 PPPagedLookasideList : [32] _GENERAL_LOOKASIDE_POOL
   +0x2c80 MsrIa32TsxCtrl   : Uint8B
   +0x2c88 DeferredReadyListHead : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x2c90 MmPageFaultCount : Int4B
   +0x2c94 MmCopyOnWriteCount : Int4B
   +0x2c98 MmTransitionCount : Int4B
   +0x2c9c MmDemandZeroCount : Int4B
   +0x2ca0 MmPageReadCount  : Int4B
   +0x2ca4 MmPageReadIoCount : Int4B
   +0x2ca8 MmDirtyPagesWriteCount : Int4B
   +0x2cac MmDirtyWriteIoCount : Int4B
   +0x2cb0 MmMappedPagesWriteCount : Int4B
   +0x2cb4 MmMappedWriteIoCount : Int4B
   +0x2cb8 KeSystemCalls    : Uint4B
   +0x2cbc KeContextSwitches : Uint4B
   +0x2cc0 LdtSelector      : Uint2B
   +0x2cc2 PrcbPad40        : Uint2B
   +0x2cc4 CcFastReadNoWait : Uint4B
   +0x2cc8 CcFastReadWait   : Uint4B
   +0x2ccc CcFastReadNotPossible : Uint4B
   +0x2cd0 CcCopyReadNoWait : Uint4B
   +0x2cd4 CcCopyReadWait   : Uint4B
   +0x2cd8 CcCopyReadNoWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x2cdc IoReadOperationCount : Int4B
   +0x2ce0 IoWriteOperationCount : Int4B
   +0x2ce4 IoOtherOperationCount : Int4B
   +0x2ce8 IoReadTransferCount : _LARGE_INTEGER
   +0x2cf0 IoWriteTransferCount : _LARGE_INTEGER
   +0x2cf8 IoOtherTransferCount : _LARGE_INTEGER
   +0x2d00 PacketBarrier    : Int4B
   +0x2d04 TargetCount      : Int4B
   +0x2d08 IpiFrozen        : Uint4B
   +0x2d10 IsrDpcStats      : Ptr64 Void
   +0x2d18 DeviceInterrupts : Uint4B
   +0x2d1c LookasideIrpFloat : Int4B
   +0x2d20 InterruptLastCount : Uint4B
   +0x2d24 InterruptRate    : Uint4B
   +0x2d28 PrcbPad41        : [22] Uint4B
   +0x2d80 DpcData          : [2] _KDPC_DATA
   +0x2dd0 DpcStack         : Ptr64 Void
   +0x2dd8 MaximumDpcQueueDepth : Int4B
   +0x2ddc DpcRequestRate   : Uint4B
   +0x2de0 MinimumDpcRate   : Uint4B
   +0x2de4 DpcLastCount     : Uint4B
   +0x2de8 ThreadDpcEnable  : UChar
   +0x2de9 QuantumEnd       : UChar
   +0x2dea DpcRoutineActive : UChar
   +0x2deb IdleSchedule     : UChar
   +0x2dec DpcRequestSummary : Int4B
   +0x2dec DpcRequestSlot   : [2] Int2B
   +0x2dec NormalDpcState   : Int2B
   +0x2dee ThreadDpcState   : Int2B
   +0x2dec DpcNormalProcessingActive : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcNormalProcessingRequested : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcNormalThreadSignal : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcNormalTimerExpiration : Pos 3, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcNormalDpcPresent : Pos 4, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcNormalLocalInterrupt : Pos 5, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcNormalSpare   : Pos 6, 10 Bits
   +0x2dec DpcThreadActive  : Pos 16, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcThreadRequested : Pos 17, 1 Bit
   +0x2dec DpcThreadSpare   : Pos 18, 14 Bits
   +0x2df0 LastTimerHand    : Uint4B
   +0x2df4 LastTick         : Uint4B
   +0x2df8 ClockInterrupts  : Uint4B
   +0x2dfc ReadyScanTick    : Uint4B
   +0x2e00 InterruptObject  : [256] Ptr64 Void
   +0x3600 TimerTable       : _KTIMER_TABLE
   +0x5800 DpcGate          : _KGATE
   +0x5818 PrcbPad52        : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5820 CallDpc          : _KDPC
   +0x5860 ClockKeepAlive   : Int4B
   +0x5864 PrcbPad60        : [2] UChar
   +0x5866 NmiActive        : Uint2B
   +0x5868 DpcWatchdogPeriod : Int4B
   +0x586c DpcWatchdogCount : Int4B
   +0x5870 KeSpinLockOrdering : Int4B
   +0x5874 PrcbPad70        : [1] Uint4B
   +0x5878 CachedPtes       : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5880 WaitListHead     : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x5890 WaitLock         : Uint8B
   +0x5898 ReadySummary     : Uint4B
   +0x589c AffinitizedSelectionMask : Int4B
   +0x58a0 QueueIndex       : Uint4B
   +0x58a4 PrcbPad75        : [3] Uint4B
   +0x58b0 TimerExpirationDpc : _KDPC
   +0x58f0 ScbQueue         : _RTL_RB_TREE
   +0x5900 DispatcherReadyListHead : [32] _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x5b00 InterruptCount   : Uint4B
   +0x5b04 KernelTime       : Uint4B
   +0x5b08 UserTime         : Uint4B
   +0x5b0c DpcTime          : Uint4B
   +0x5b10 InterruptTime    : Uint4B
   +0x5b14 AdjustDpcThreshold : Uint4B
   +0x5b18 DebuggerSavedIRQL : UChar
   +0x5b19 GroupSchedulingOverQuota : UChar
   +0x5b1a DeepSleep        : UChar
   +0x5b1b PrcbPad80        : [1] UChar
   +0x5b1c ScbOffset        : Uint4B
   +0x5b20 DpcTimeCount     : Uint4B
   +0x5b24 DpcTimeLimit     : Uint4B
   +0x5b28 PeriodicCount    : Uint4B
   +0x5b2c PeriodicBias     : Uint4B
   +0x5b30 AvailableTime    : Uint4B
   +0x5b34 KeExceptionDispatchCount : Uint4B
   +0x5b38 StartCycles      : Uint8B
   +0x5b40 GenerationTarget : Uint8B
   +0x5b48 AffinitizedCycles : Uint8B
   +0x5b50 PrcbPad81        : [2] Uint8B
   +0x5b60 MmSpinLockOrdering : Int4B
   +0x5b64 PageColor        : Uint4B
   +0x5b68 NodeColor        : Uint4B
   +0x5b6c NodeShiftedColor : Uint4B
   +0x5b70 SecondaryColorMask : Uint4B
   +0x5b74 PrcbPad83        : Uint4B
   +0x5b78 CycleTime        : Uint8B
   +0x5b80 CcFastMdlReadNoWait : Uint4B
   +0x5b84 CcFastMdlReadWait : Uint4B
   +0x5b88 CcFastMdlReadNotPossible : Uint4B
   +0x5b8c CcMapDataNoWait  : Uint4B
   +0x5b90 CcMapDataWait    : Uint4B
   +0x5b94 CcPinMappedDataCount : Uint4B
   +0x5b98 CcPinReadNoWait  : Uint4B
   +0x5b9c CcPinReadWait    : Uint4B
   +0x5ba0 CcMdlReadNoWait  : Uint4B
   +0x5ba4 CcMdlReadWait    : Uint4B
   +0x5ba8 CcLazyWriteHotSpots : Uint4B
   +0x5bac CcLazyWriteIos   : Uint4B
   +0x5bb0 CcLazyWritePages : Uint4B
   +0x5bb4 CcDataFlushes    : Uint4B
   +0x5bb8 CcDataPages      : Uint4B
   +0x5bbc CcLostDelayedWrites : Uint4B
   +0x5bc0 CcFastReadResourceMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bc4 CcCopyReadWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bc8 CcFastMdlReadResourceMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bcc CcMapDataNoWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bd0 CcMapDataWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bd4 CcPinReadNoWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bd8 CcPinReadWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5bdc CcMdlReadNoWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5be0 CcMdlReadWaitMiss : Uint4B
   +0x5be4 CcReadAheadIos   : Uint4B
   +0x5be8 MmCacheTransitionCount : Int4B
   +0x5bec MmCacheReadCount : Int4B
   +0x5bf0 MmCacheIoCount   : Int4B
   +0x5bf4 PrcbPad91        : [3] Uint4B
   +0x5c00 PowerState       : _PROCESSOR_POWER_STATE
   +0x5de0 ScbList          : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x5df0 PrcbPad92        : [19] Uint4B
   +0x5e3c KeAlignmentFixupCount : Uint4B
   +0x5e40 DpcWatchdogDpc   : _KDPC
   +0x5e80 DpcWatchdogTimer : _KTIMER
   +0x5ec0 Cache            : [5] _CACHE_DESCRIPTOR
   +0x5efc CacheCount       : Uint4B
   +0x5f00 CachedCommit     : Uint4B
   +0x5f04 CachedResidentAvailable : Uint4B
   +0x5f08 HyperPte         : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5f10 WheaInfo         : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5f18 EtwSupport       : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5f20 InterruptObjectPool : _SLIST_HEADER
   +0x5f30 HypercallPageList : _SLIST_HEADER
   +0x5f40 HypercallPageVirtual : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5f48 VirtualApicAssist : Ptr64 Void
   +0x5f50 StatisticsPage   : Ptr64 Uint8B
   +0x5f58 PackageProcessorSet : _KAFFINITY_EX
   +0x6000 SharedReadyQueueMask : Uint8B
   +0x6008 SharedReadyQueue : Ptr64 _KSHARED_READY_QUEUE
   +0x6010 CoreProcessorSet : Uint8B
   +0x6018 ScanSiblingMask  : Uint8B
   +0x6020 LLCMask          : Uint8B
   +0x6028 CacheProcessorMask : [5] Uint8B
   +0x6050 ScanSiblingIndex : Uint4B
   +0x6054 SharedReadyQueueOffset : Uint4B
   +0x6058 ProcessorProfileControlArea : Ptr64 _PROCESSOR_PROFILE_CONTROL_AREA
   +0x6060 ProfileEventIndexAddress : Ptr64 Void
   +0x6068 TrappedSecurityDomain : Uint8B
   +0x6070 BpbState         : UChar
   +0x6070 BpbCpuIdle       : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x6070 BpbFlushRsbOnTrap : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x6070 BpbIbpbOnReturn  : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x6070 BpbIbpbOnTrap    : Pos 3, 1 Bit
   +0x6070 BpbReserved1     : Pos 4, 1 Bit
   +0x6070 BpbFlushRsbOnReturn : Pos 5, 1 Bit
   +0x6070 BpbReserved      : Pos 6, 2 Bits
   +0x6071 BpbFeatures      : UChar
   +0x6071 BpbClearOnIdle   : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x6071 BpbEnabled       : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x6071 BpbSmep          : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x6071 BpbFeaturesReserved : Pos 3, 5 Bits
   +0x6072 BpbCurrentSpecCtrl : UChar
   +0x6073 BpbKernelSpecCtrl : UChar
   +0x6074 BpbNmiSpecCtrl   : UChar
   +0x6075 BpbUserSpecCtrl  : UChar
   +0x6076 BpbPad           : [2] UChar
   +0x6078 PrcbPad94        : Uint8B
   +0x6080 SynchCounters    : _SYNCH_COUNTERS
   +0x6138 PteBitCache      : Uint8B
   +0x6140 PteBitOffset     : Uint4B
   +0x6148 FsCounters       : _FILESYSTEM_DISK_COUNTERS
   +0x6158 VendorString     : [13] UChar
   +0x6165 PrcbPad10        : [3] UChar
   +0x6168 FeatureBits      : Uint8B
   +0x6170 PrcbPad11        : Uint4B
   +0x6178 UpdateSignature  : _LARGE_INTEGER
   +0x6180 Context          : Ptr64 _CONTEXT
   +0x6188 ContextFlagsInit : Uint4B
   +0x6190 ExtendedState    : Ptr64 _XSAVE_AREA
   +0x6198 IsrStack         : Ptr64 Void
   +0x61a0 EntropyTimingState : _KENTROPY_TIMING_STATE
   +0x62f0 PrcbPad111       : Uint8B
   +0x62f8 PrcbPad112       : [7] Uint8B
   +0x6330 AbSelfIoBoostsList : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x6338 AbPropagateBoostsList : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x6340 AbDpc            : _KDPC
   +0x6380 IoIrpStackProfilerCurrent : _IOP_IRP_STACK_PROFILER
   +0x63d4 IoIrpStackProfilerPrevious : _IOP_IRP_STACK_PROFILER
   +0x6428 TimerExpirationTrace : [16] _KTIMER_EXPIRATION_TRACE
   +0x6528 TimerExpirationTraceCount : Uint4B
   +0x6540 Mailbox          : Ptr64 _REQUEST_MAILBOX
   +0x6548 PrcbPad130       : [7] Uint8B
   +0x6580 ProcessorSignature : Uint4B
   +0x6584 PrcbPad135       : [2300] UChar
   +0x6e80 KernelDirectoryTableBase : Uint8B
   +0x6e88 RspBaseShadow    : Uint8B
   +0x6e90 UserRspShadow    : Uint8B
   +0x6e98 ShadowFlags      : Uint4B
   +0x6e9c VerwSelector     : Uint2B
   +0x6e9e PrcbPad139       : Uint2B
   +0x6ea0 PrcbPad140       : [508] Uint8B
   +0x7e80 RequestMailbox   : [1] _REQUEST_MAILBOX

lkd> dt _KTHREAD
nt!_KTHREAD
   +0x000 Header           : _DISPATCHER_HEADER
   +0x018 SListFaultAddress : Ptr64 Void
   +0x020 QuantumTarget    : Uint8B
   +0x028 InitialStack     : Ptr64 Void
   +0x030 StackLimit       : Ptr64 Void
   +0x038 StackBase        : Ptr64 Void
   +0x040 ThreadLock       : Uint8B
   +0x048 CycleTime        : Uint8B
   +0x050 CurrentRunTime   : Uint4B
   +0x054 ExpectedRunTime  : Uint4B
   +0x058 KernelStack      : Ptr64 Void
   +0x060 StateSaveArea    : Ptr64 _XSAVE_FORMAT
   +0x068 SchedulingGroup  : Ptr64 _KSCHEDULING_GROUP
   +0x070 WaitRegister     : _KWAIT_STATUS_REGISTER
   +0x071 Running          : UChar
   +0x072 Alerted          : [2] UChar
   +0x074 SpareMiscFlag0   : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ReadyTransition  : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ProcessReadyQueue : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x074 WaitNext         : Pos 3, 1 Bit
   +0x074 SystemAffinityActive : Pos 4, 1 Bit
   +0x074 Alertable        : Pos 5, 1 Bit
   +0x074 UserStackWalkActive : Pos 6, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ApcInterruptRequest : Pos 7, 1 Bit
   +0x074 QuantumEndMigrate : Pos 8, 1 Bit
   +0x074 UmsDirectedSwitchEnable : Pos 9, 1 Bit
   +0x074 TimerActive      : Pos 10, 1 Bit
   +0x074 SystemThread     : Pos 11, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ProcessDetachActive : Pos 12, 1 Bit
   +0x074 CalloutActive    : Pos 13, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ScbReadyQueue    : Pos 14, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ApcQueueable     : Pos 15, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ReservedStackInUse : Pos 16, 1 Bit
   +0x074 UmsPerformingSyscall : Pos 17, 1 Bit
   +0x074 ApcPendingReload : Pos 18, 1 Bit
   +0x074 TimerSuspended   : Pos 19, 1 Bit
   +0x074 SuspendedWaitMode : Pos 20, 1 Bit
   +0x074 Reserved         : Pos 21, 11 Bits
   +0x074 MiscFlags        : Int4B
   +0x078 AutoAlignment    : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x078 DisableBoost     : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x078 UserAffinitySet  : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x078 AlertedByThreadId : Pos 3, 1 Bit
   +0x078 QuantumDonation  : Pos 4, 1 Bit
   +0x078 EnableStackSwap  : Pos 5, 1 Bit
   +0x078 GuiThread        : Pos 6, 1 Bit
   +0x078 DisableQuantum   : Pos 7, 1 Bit
   +0x078 ChargeOnlySchedulingGroup : Pos 8, 1 Bit
   +0x078 DeferPreemption  : Pos 9, 1 Bit
   +0x078 QueueDeferPreemption : Pos 10, 1 Bit
   +0x078 ForceDeferSchedule : Pos 11, 1 Bit
   +0x078 SharedReadyQueueAffinity : Pos 12, 1 Bit
   +0x078 FreezeCount      : Pos 13, 1 Bit
   +0x078 TerminationApcRequest : Pos 14, 1 Bit
   +0x078 AutoBoostEntriesExhausted : Pos 15, 1 Bit
   +0x078 KernelStackResident : Pos 16, 1 Bit
   +0x078 EtwStackTraceApcInserted : Pos 17, 8 Bits
   +0x078 ReservedFlags    : Pos 25, 7 Bits
   +0x078 ThreadFlags      : Int4B
   +0x07c Spare0           : Uint4B
   +0x080 SystemCallNumber : Uint4B
   +0x084 Spare1           : Uint4B
   +0x088 FirstArgument    : Ptr64 Void
   +0x090 TrapFrame        : Ptr64 _KTRAP_FRAME
   +0x098 ApcState         : _KAPC_STATE
   +0x098 ApcStateFill     : [43] UChar
   +0x0c3 Priority         : Char
   +0x0c4 UserIdealProcessor : Uint4B
   +0x0c8 WaitStatus       : Int8B
   +0x0d0 WaitBlockList    : Ptr64 _KWAIT_BLOCK
   +0x0d8 WaitListEntry    : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x0d8 SwapListEntry    : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x0e8 Queue            : Ptr64 _DISPATCHER_HEADER
   +0x0f0 Teb              : Ptr64 Void
   +0x0f8 RelativeTimerBias : Uint8B
   +0x100 Timer            : _KTIMER
   +0x140 WaitBlock        : [4] _KWAIT_BLOCK
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill4   : [20] UChar
   +0x154 ContextSwitches  : Uint4B
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill5   : [68] UChar
   +0x184 State            : UChar
   +0x185 NpxState         : Char
   +0x186 WaitIrql         : UChar
   +0x187 WaitMode         : Char
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill6   : [116] UChar
   +0x1b4 WaitTime         : Uint4B
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill7   : [164] UChar
   +0x1e4 KernelApcDisable : Int2B
   +0x1e6 SpecialApcDisable : Int2B
   +0x1e4 CombinedApcDisable : Uint4B
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill8   : [40] UChar
   +0x168 ThreadCounters   : Ptr64 _KTHREAD_COUNTERS
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill9   : [88] UChar
   +0x198 XStateSave       : Ptr64 _XSTATE_SAVE
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill10  : [136] UChar
   +0x1c8 Win32Thread      : Ptr64 Void
   +0x140 WaitBlockFill11  : [176] UChar
   +0x1f0 Ucb              : Ptr64 _UMS_CONTROL_BLOCK
   +0x1f8 Uch              : Ptr64 _KUMS_CONTEXT_HEADER
   +0x200 TebMappedLowVa   : Ptr64 Void
   +0x208 QueueListEntry   : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x218 NextProcessor    : Uint4B
   +0x218 NextProcessorNumber : Pos 0, 31 Bits
   +0x218 SharedReadyQueue : Pos 31, 1 Bit
   +0x21c QueuePriority    : Int4B
   +0x220 Process          : Ptr64 _KPROCESS
   +0x228 UserAffinity     : _GROUP_AFFINITY
   +0x228 UserAffinityFill : [10] UChar
   +0x232 PreviousMode     : Char
   +0x233 BasePriority     : Char
   +0x234 PriorityDecrement : Char
   +0x234 ForegroundBoost  : Pos 0, 4 Bits
   +0x234 UnusualBoost     : Pos 4, 4 Bits
   +0x235 Preempted        : UChar
   +0x236 AdjustReason     : UChar
   +0x237 AdjustIncrement  : Char
   +0x238 Affinity         : _GROUP_AFFINITY
   +0x238 AffinityFill     : [10] UChar
   +0x242 ApcStateIndex    : UChar
   +0x243 WaitBlockCount   : UChar
   +0x244 IdealProcessor   : Uint4B
   +0x248 ApcStatePointer  : [2] Ptr64 _KAPC_STATE
   +0x258 SavedApcState    : _KAPC_STATE
   +0x258 SavedApcStateFill : [43] UChar
   +0x283 WaitReason       : UChar
   +0x284 SuspendCount     : Char
   +0x285 Saturation       : Char
   +0x286 SListFaultCount  : Uint2B
   +0x288 SchedulerApc     : _KAPC
   +0x288 SchedulerApcFill0 : [1] UChar
   +0x289 ResourceIndex    : UChar
   +0x288 SchedulerApcFill1 : [3] UChar
   +0x28b QuantumReset     : UChar
   +0x288 SchedulerApcFill2 : [4] UChar
   +0x28c KernelTime       : Uint4B
   +0x288 SchedulerApcFill3 : [64] UChar
   +0x2c8 WaitPrcb         : Ptr64 _KPRCB
   +0x288 SchedulerApcFill4 : [72] UChar
   +0x2d0 LegoData         : Ptr64 Void
   +0x288 SchedulerApcFill5 : [83] UChar
   +0x2db CallbackNestingLevel : UChar
   +0x2dc UserTime         : Uint4B
   +0x2e0 SuspendEvent     : _KEVENT
   +0x2f8 ThreadListEntry  : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x308 MutantListHead   : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x318 LockEntriesFreeList : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x320 LockEntries      : [6] _KLOCK_ENTRY
   +0x560 PropagateBoostsEntry : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x568 IoSelfBoostsEntry : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x570 PriorityFloorCounts : [16] UChar
   +0x580 PriorityFloorSummary : Uint4B
   +0x584 AbCompletedIoBoostCount : Int4B
   +0x588 AbReferenceCount : Int2B
   +0x58a AbFreeEntryCount : UChar
   +0x58b AbWaitEntryCount : UChar
   +0x58c ForegroundLossTime : Uint4B
   +0x590 GlobalForegroundListEntry : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x590 ForegroundDpcStackListEntry : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x598 InGlobalForegroundList : Uint8B
   +0x5a0 ReadOperationCount : Int8B
   +0x5a8 WriteOperationCount : Int8B
   +0x5b0 OtherOperationCount : Int8B
   +0x5b8 ReadTransferCount : Int8B
   +0x5c0 WriteTransferCount : Int8B
   +0x5c8 OtherTransferCount : Int8B

lkd> dt _KAPC_STATE
nt!_KAPC_STATE
   +0x000 ApcListHead      : [2] _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x020 Process          : Ptr64 _KPROCESS
   +0x028 InProgressFlags  : UChar
   +0x028 KernelApcInProgress : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x028 SpecialApcInProgress : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x029 KernelApcPending : UChar
   +0x02a UserApcPending   : UChar
```

Comment: 1) there is no "traversal" since that implies a loop 2) where did you get your offsets ... the code uses `188h` and `B8h` 3) you need to know the definition of the structs to know where each member is.

Comment: @Jester thank you. You're absolutely correct that there is  no traversing per se but that is my understanding of it. I've added the definitions for the respective structs. Hope that helps.

Comment: You did not show `_KTHREAD`. But I assume it has a process pointer at offset `B8h`. Which part is confusing?

Comment: @Jester thank you again. I will add the definition of the _KTHREAD structure, my apologies. I kind of figured that out too as I manually walked the _KTHREAD struct and reached the _KPROCESS member located at 0x020 of the Process member of the _KAPC_STATE struct. Thank you again.

Comment: Yeah, `ApcState` is at `98h`, and the `Process` is an additional `20h` bytes in, giving you the `b8h`.